# Make soft body particles behave independently

Tags: particles, soft-body

I am trying to create an animation where soft body particles are emitted, and then fill in a certain space (a bowl in my case), but the problem is, they all behave the same way the instance object behaves, meaning that when the instance object changes its shape, so do all of the particles in exactly the same way, but refuse to change shape independently. This, along with not doing what I want it to, also makes the particles bounce around the bowl like crazy, since being hard, they intersect with the walls of the bowl and get pushed out at a very high velocity. Is it possible to make all of the particles behave independently in blender?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this with the help of animation nodes and particles, here is a similar tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1ysjPeLKSQ

Comment: thank you, this video does allow me to do everything I wanted to do.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX  How is this done for the softbody? It seems like doing it with rbody is easy with putting them in a rigid body collection. The softbody is a modifier